# Django local model inside other model that consists from 2 models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

To make it clearer, I want to create an **e-commerce** app for installment stores

*I prepared a short HTML template at the bottom of the question*

I have the following model:

```
class App_form(models.Model): #This is the head model

    id_customer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,12}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '998981234567'. Up to 12 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=13, unique=True)

    #Models which I should combine and which will be named as: products_with_period model and it should belong only and only to this App_form model

    warehouse = models.ManyToManyField(Warehouse)
    product_period = models.OneToOneField(Product_period, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.surname

#Product period

class Product_period(models.Model):
    product_period = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    product_percent = models.FloatField()
    product_periodvalue = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_period

#Warehouse model 

class Warehouse(models.Model):
    category_product = models.ForeignKey(Category_product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    condition = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    barcode = models.BigIntegerField()
    f_price = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

What I want to achieve in my *Rest Api* out only from combined `products_with_period` model

```
products_with_period = [{
        id: 1,    
        product_name: " ", 
        product_fprice: " ", 
        product_period: {
            "id": 2,  
            "product_period_name": " ", 
            "product_period_percent": " ",  
        },
        {
        id: 2, 
        product_name: " ",  
        product_fprice: " ",  
        product_period: {
            "product_period": " ",  
            "product_period_percent": " ",
        },
    }],
```

Here is the HTML template, which explains the essence

```js
function addProduct() {
  var table = document.getElementById("ProductTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = `
  <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" >
        <option value="1">Smartphone</option>
        <option value="2">Smart TV</option>
        <option value="3">Laptop</option>
        <option value="4">Desktop</option>
        <option value="5">Sofa</option>
        <option value="6">Bicycle</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  `;
  cell2.innerHTML = `
   <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" >
        <option value="1">3 months</option>
        <option value="2">6 months</option>
        <option value="3">12 months</option>
        <option value="4">24 months</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  `;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 p-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="c_name">Customer name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="c_name" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="c_phone">Customer phone:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="c_phone" type="tel">
      </div>

    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="ProductTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product name:</th>
          <th>Installment period:</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Smartphone</option>
                <option value="2">Smart TV</option>
                <option value="3">Laptop</option>
                <option value="4">Desktop</option>
                <option value="5">Sofa</option>
                <option value="6">Bicycle</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control">
                <option value="1">3 months</option>
                <option value="2">6 months</option>
                <option value="3">12 months</option>
                <option value="4">24 months</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="addProduct()">add new product</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (which is not using Django-rest and there is probably a way to do this with serializers, but this is what I came up with off the top of my head):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def product_api(request):
    app_forms = App_form.objects.filter(product_period__isnull=False).all()
    products_with_period = []
    data = {}
    for form in app_forms:
        data['id'] = form.id
        data['product_name'] = form.name
        ...
        data['product_period']['id'] = form.product_period.id
        data['product_period']['product_period_name'] = form.product_period.product_period
        ...
        products_with_period.append(data)
        data = {}
    if request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse(products_with_period)
    else:
        return HttpBadRequest()
```

This can then be injested by an AJAX function in the template:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#button_or_object_id").click(function(){
                          $.ajax({ 
                              url: '{% url 'product_api' %}',
                              type: "GET",
                              dataType: "json",
                              cache: false
                           }).done(function(products_with_period) {
                                // do something with the products_with_period data
                           });
                      });
                  });
        </script>
```

Otherwise, you can also render it in the context:

```
def product_api(request):
    app_forms = App_form.objects.filter(product_period__isnull=False).all()
    products_with_period = []
    data = {}
    for form in app_forms:
        data['id'] = form.id
        data['product_name'] = form.name
        ...
        data['product_period']['id'] = form.product_period.id
        data['product_period']['product_period_name'] = form.product_period.product_period
        ...
        products_with_period.append(data)
        data = {}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context={'products_with_period':products_with_period})
```

And then render the array of dicts in your template manually.